# Call a JNI method from another JNI method

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

Is it possible to call a JNI C  function inside another JNI C function? (directly or indirectly), or, a JNI function inside a normal C function?

For example:

```
int inverse_transform(double real[], double imag[], size_t n) {
return Java_com_example_ffttest_FFTActivity_transform(imag, real, n);
```

}

and `inverse_transform()` is later called inside another method.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_ffttest_FFTActivity_convolve(...)
                     {
                          ....
                          inverse_transform();
                                }
```

Does this work? I tried but it gives me errors about parameters and I don't know how to use *env and obj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly it's possible. Those are just functions with funny names as far as C is concerned.

One word of caution though - if the JNI function uses its `JNIEnv` parameter, you need to pass a valid one from a non-JNI function.

Comment: how to choose a valid one? should i just write *JNIEnv v; and add it to the function header?

Comment: Yeah, just make it a part of the non-JNI function header and pass it around.

Answer (score 0):

At the end JNI methods are normal c++ methods so offcourse you can do it .